# QuestPDF Text is not displaying (.NET Core running on 64bit Amazon Linux)

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux

I have developed an application in .NET Core 5, I am using QuestPDF (2022.2.6). Generated PDF is working fine on my local machine (Windows 11), but when I deploy this application to .NET Core running on 64bit Amazon Linux, it is not working. The text is not displaying.

Note: I am using `SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies` for Linux support. Image is also rendered properly.

Local environment (Windows 11) - output

[image]

.NET Core running on 64bit Amazon Linux environment - output, yellow marked, there is no text

[image]

Here is my code block

```
container.Row(row =>
        {
            row.RelativeItem().Column(column =>
            {
                column.Item().Text("SKIN SCAN RESULTS", TextStyle.Default.Size(20).SemiBold().Color("#0DD0D9"));
            });

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(logo-url))
            {
                row.RelativeItem().AlignRight().Height(35).PaddingBottom(5).Image(GetImage(logo-url), ImageScaling.FitHeight);
            }
        });
```

Is there anything I missed in my reference ?